# How can I model a recursive string pattern with only one argument passed?

Tags: c++, string, recursion, char, function-definition

I recently ran into a pattern recursive problem that I cannot solve and I was wondering if anyone could give me some hints or ideas.

The pattern changes depending on even or odd values of `n`. For instance, if `n` is even, there should be `**` output at the center surrounded by `(` and `)`. If, however, the `n` value is odd, there should only be one `*` printed at the center and surrounded by `(` and `)`.

I've been able to solve this by altering the `myString` function to accept two variables and use one as the "tracker" to maintain the original `n` value as the recursion carries on, but this problem has to be solved with only one argument passed. I'm really at a loss here.

Sample Patterns:
`myString(1)` should output `"*"`
`myString(2)` should output `"**"`
`myString(4)` should output `"(**)"`
`myString(9)` should output `"((((*))))"`

I attempted to solve this by altering the `myString()` function to take two variables as arguments, but this is not a valid solution, as apparently this can be solved with only one argument `n` passed.

My Attempt:

```cpp
string myString(int n, int m) {
    string tempString;
    int middle = round(m / 2);

    if (m == 1)
    {
        return "*";
    }
    else if (m == 2)
    {
        return "**";
    }

    if (n > middle + 1)
    {
        tempString += '(' + myString(n - 1,m);
    }
    else if (n == middle + 1)
    {
        if (m % 2)
        {
            tempString +=  '*';
            n -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tempString += "**";
            n -= 2;
        }
        tempString += myString(n, m);
    }
    else if (n < middle + 1 && n > 0)
    {
        tempString += ')' + myString(n - 1, m);
    }

    return tempString;
}
```

Comment: This feels like homework so I'm reluctant to just give the answer. But here's a hint: You're well on track with your n==1 and n==2 conditions. Notice how any higher n will add ( and ) for each 2 increments

Comment: Why are you trying to solve this using recursion? This can be solved much easier in just a few lines of code, using the `std::string` constructor that takes a character and a count, no recursion needed, eg: `size_t stars = 2 - (n % 2); size_t parens = (n - stars) / 2; return string(parens, '(') + string(stars, '*') + string(parens, ')');` [Online Demo](https://ideone.com/hbGsyD)

Comment: I agree that this is a poor use case for recursion. I have to solve it this way for a class, and so far none of my peers have solved it. The professor did not give any hints or ideas when I reached out to him other than it can be solved in the way it is set up. Also thank you for editing my post to be more coherent.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld Thank you for your response. I was mainly looking for hints and ideas to solve this myself when I posted this. It is for a class assignment and in the future if I post more questions of a similar nature I will be more specific about not wanting solved answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is too complicated, unclear and error prone. In some paths of the function execution the variable `n` is not even used.

The function can look much simpler.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

std::string string_pattern( unsigned int n )
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return {};
    }
    else if ( n <= 2 )
    {
        return std::string(  n, '*' );
    }
    else
    {
        return '(' + string_pattern( n - 2 ) + ')';
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted( string_pattern( i ) ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
""
"*"
"**"
"(*)"
"(**)"
"((*))"
"((**))"
"(((*)))"
"(((**)))"
"((((*))))"
```

If your compiler does not support the manipulator `std::quoted` or you do not want to output quoted strings then just remove it together with the header `<iomanip>`.

```
std::cout << string_pattern( i ) << '\n';
```

Actually the function can look even more simpler having only one return statement like

```
std::string string_pattern( unsigned int n )
{
    return n <= 2 ? std::string( n, '*' ) : '(' + string_pattern( n - 2 ) + ')';
}
```

The used within the function constructor of the class `std::string`

```
constexpr basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

does not introduce a restriction on the value of the parameter `n`. So it may be called with `n` equal to `0`.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer. I have a question regarding your solution so I can better understand it. When you have return std::string( n, '*') does that simply return '*' char for each n value? Like for example if n was 3 would that function return "***"?

Comment: @Solidsnake1209 It means to construct a string with n characters initialized by the character '*'. The class std::string has such a constructor.